# Which is the correct way of using a class method into its subclass that maybe won't be instantiated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclassing, private-members

Given the parent class:

```
class Parent():
   _private_attr: Int = None

   @classmethod
   def set_private_attr(cls, value):
      if not type(value) is int:
         raise ValueError()
      cls._private_attr = value
```

How do I use `set_private_attr` into a subclass, given that maybe it will not be instantiated and therefore I can't use `super()` in `__init__`?

E.g.:

```
def SubClass(Parent):
   Parent.set_private_attr(a_value)
```

Is that right? There's is a better way of doing this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Should the second example not be `class SubClass(Parent)`, in which case it *inherits* the `set_private_attr` class method? If you want to override the inherited `_private_attr` value during subclass creation, `_private_attr = a_value` will do it; you don't need to call the method.

Comment: I updated the question. The set_private_attr method also does a validation, so I would like to use it.

Comment: You'd have to call it *after* class creation, then - `class SubClass(Parent): pass; SubClass.set_private_attr(a_value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit from Parent, then the derived class can use the `set_private_attr()` class method.

Here's an example.

```
class Parent():
   _private_attr = None

   @classmethod
   def set_private_attr(cls, value):
      cls._private_attr = value

class Foo(Parent):
    pass

foo = Foo()
foo.set_private_attr("bar")
```

If you want to set this before constructing the derived class:

```
Foo.set_private_attr("bar")
foo = Foo()
print(foo._private_attr)
```

Comment: The problem is that Foo will not be instantiated.

Comment: You can do it before instantiating the class as well. I've edited my post to show that.